# combining data files and appying function to a column

Tags: r, function

I need to combine two data files that both have the following structure, with Daily.Ave the only variable that changes between the two.

[image]

My (probably rather dumb) question is, how do i read in the two data files, while at the same time applying a function to the Daily.Ave column such that DataFile2$Daily.Ave - DataFile1$Daily.Ave?

I would like to end up with a new data file in which columns 1:4 remain the same but column 5 is the difference between the two 'scenarios'.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do :

```
cbind(DataFile1[1:4], diff_ave = DataFile2$Daily.Ave - DataFile1$Daily.Ave)
```